# MIPS Help: Recursive Functions

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator, qtspim

I'm trying to code this recursive function into MIPS.
My problem is I'm not sure how I can do the recursive step.
I'm pretty sure I got the rest correct.

```
int recur(int n) {
    if(n == 1 || n == 2) {
           return 2;
    } else {
           return (n-4)+n*recur(n-2);
    }
}
```

```
.data

promptMessage: .asciiz "Enter a number that is greater than or equal to 0: "
resultMessage: .asciiz "\nThe answer is: "
input: .word 0
answer: .word 0

.text
.globl main

main:
#Read the number from the user
li $v0, 4           
la $a0, promptMessage       
syscall

li $v0, 5           
syscall         

sw $v0, input           

#Call the function
lw $a0, input           
jal recur           
sw $v0, answer      

#Display result
li $v0, 4
la $a0, resultMessage       
syscall

li $v0, 1           
lw $a0, answer          
syscall

.globl recur

recur:
addi $sp, $sp, -8       
sw $a0, 0($sp)          
sw $ra, 4($sp)          

#Base Case  if(n == 0 || n == 1) return 2;
li $v0, 2
beq $a0, $zero, DONE
beq $a0, 1, DONE

#RECURSIVE STEP
addi $a0, $a0, -2       
jal recur
```

Comment: As a courtesy to others, if you see your question come out with broken formatting please fix it yourself. Next time use the preview too. As for the code, you got the recursion correct, all that is left is to  evaluate the formula and return from the function.

Comment: Andrew, tell us in your own words what it means when a function is "recursive".

Comment: If n <= 0, then the function will recurse until it runs out of stack space. It might be better if the C example started with if(n <= 2)return 2;

Comment: @rcgldr The C code has this issue, but OP's comment in the mips code [and the tests done] are different (e.g. `if (n == 0 || n == 1) return 2`). In my answer, I handled the <0 case as "stop prompting" but I guess it's an open question as to which is the desired base case. Since this seems more like a basic recursion program, the actual base case may not matter (ie. getting the recursion correct is the bigger goal)

Comment: @CraigEstey - I didn't catch the conflict between the C base case and the assembly comment about the base case. Since $V0 is loaded with a 2, couldn't the code just compare $a0 with $v0 to check for < 2? It's still two instructions though, compare, followed by a conditional branch, versus two conditional branches.

Comment: @rcgldr It's good that you noticed the C code, because I didn't notice it. I left that part of OP's mips code intact, but, for tidiness they should match. I tested for values `0->2, 1->2, 2->2, 3->5, 4->8, 5->26` [and many random others]. Maybe OP will edit post to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a great job. Creating C code first. You were very close.

I had to add the calculation step and the function epilog code.

Also, there was a bug where after main prints the number, there was *no* syscall 10 (exit) so the code would just fall through and recurse infinitely.

I reworked the C code slightly so it would be more compatible with the MIPS code.

Just for fun, and ease of testing, I changed main to loop and reprompt until it gets a negative number.

I've cleaned up and tested the code, added annotations [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .data

# NOTE: these should appear first to maintain alignment to a 4 byte boundary
# (or the .align 4 will do it) otherwise, the lw/sw ops can fail on an
# alignment exception
    .align  4
input:      .word       0
answer:     .word       0

promptMessage:  .asciiz "Enter a number that is greater than or equal to 0 (-1 to stop): "
resultMessage:  .asciiz "\nThe answer is: "
nl:         .asciiz "\n"

    .text   .globl

main:
    # prompt user
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,promptMessage
    syscall

    # Read the number from the user
    li      $v0,5
    syscall
    sw      $v0,input

    # negative value means stop
    # NOTE: added this
    bltz    $v0,main_exit

    # Call the function
    lw      $a0,input
    jal     recur
    sw      $v0,answer

    # Display result message
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,resultMessage
    syscall

    # display number
    li      $v0,1
    lw      $a0,answer
    syscall

    # output newline
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,nl
    syscall

    # NOTE: this was added to allow multiple tries, but without it, there was
    # the bug below
    j       main

    # BUG: syscall to exit here was _missing_ so got fallthrough into "recur"
    # causing the stack to overflow
main_exit:
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

    .globl  recur

# recur -- recursion
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- the "n" value
#
# pseudo code:
# * int
# * recur(int n)
# * {
# *     int r;
# *
# *     if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
# *         return 2;
# *     }
# *
# *     r = recur(n - 2);
# *
# *     return (n - 4) + (n * r);
# * }
recur:
    addi    $sp,$sp,-8
    sw      $a0,0($sp)
    sw      $ra,4($sp)

    # Base Case  if(n == 0 || n == 1) return 2;
    li      $v0,2
    beq     $a0,$zero,recur_done
    beq     $a0,1,recur_done

    # RECURSIVE STEP
    addi    $a0,$a0,-2          # n -= 2
    jal     recur
    lw      $a0,0($sp)          # we need "n" back (not (n - 2))

    # NOTE: this calculation was missing
    mul     $v0,$v0,$a0         # r *= n (i.e. (n * r))
    addi    $a0,$a0,-4          # n -= 4 (i.e. (n - 4))
    add     $v0,$v0,$a0         # sum them

    # NOTE: this is the standard reversal for this function's stack prolog
recur_done:
    lw      $a0,0($sp)
    lw      $ra,4($sp)
    addi    $sp,$sp,8
    jr      $ra
```